# Spring Boot Error when getting object with UUID

Tags: spring, hibernate, uuid

I have 2 classes SKU Master and Item. Item is a property of SKUMaster. Item has its primary key 'id' as UUID. Each class has a table associated table (SKUMaster and Item).

When inserting a new SKU the data is inserted into the SKUMaster table. However, when retrieving all the SKUMaster we get an error (mention below)

org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]

If we make item property as an Arraylist of Items the getAll method works properly.

I have attached the sample code and the complete error below

**Item**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Item implements ItemImpl {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID",strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private UUID id;
  private String name;
  private String code;

 @OneToOne
 private Category category;

 @Value("${some.key:false}")
 private boolean isDeleted;

 @OneToOne
 private UnitOfMeasure uom;

 private float rate;

 @Value("${some.key:false}")
 private boolean qcRequired;


public Item() {
    super();
    System.out.println("default constructor ");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public Item(UUID id, String name, String code, Category category, boolean isDeleted, UnitOfMeasure uom, float rate,boolean qcRequired) {
    super();
    System.out.println("parameterised constructor "+id);
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.code = code;
    this.category = category;
    this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    this.uom = uom;
    this.rate = rate;
    this.qcRequired = qcRequired;
}
```

**SKUMaster**

```
@Entity
public class SKUMaster{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;   

  @OneToOne
  private Item item;

  @Min(value = 1, message = "Quantity should be greater than zero")
  private float quantity;

  @Min(value = 1, message = "Rate should be greater than zero")
  private float itemRate;

  @OneToOne
  private UnitOfMeasure uom;

  @Value("${some.key:false}")
  private boolean convertable;

  @NotEmpty(message = "SKU master code should be enter")
  private String skuMasterCode;

  @NotEmpty(message = "SKU master name should be enter")
  private String name;

  public SKUMaster() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public SKUMaster(int id, Item item, float quantity, float itemRate, UnitOfMeasure uom, boolean convertable,
        String skuMasterCode, String name) {
    super();
    this.setId(id);
    this.setItem(item);
    this.setQuantity(quantity);
    this.setItemRate(itemRate);
    this.setUom(uom);
    this.setConvertable(convertable);
    this.setSkuMasterCode(skuMasterCode);
    this.setName(name);
}
```

//setter and getters.

**Error**

```
 javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.taurus.arca.core.Item with id cceb595e-399d-4415-a036-1c02b3b18090
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:332) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1049) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:697) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad$EntityResolver.lambda$static$0(TwoPhaseLoad.java:657) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntityEntryLoadedState(TwoPhaseLoad.java:252) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1203) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1004) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:962) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2857) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2839) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2671) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2666) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1412) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1565) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:355) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.taurus.arca.sku.SKUMasterService.getAll(SKUMasterService.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.taurus.arca.sku.SKUMasterService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8a6daf2d.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:687) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.taurus.arca.sku.SKUMasterService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a36c3b36.getAll(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.taurus.arca.sku.SKUMasterController.getAll(SKUMasterController.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
```

**SKUMasterService getAll**

```
public ArrayList<SKUMaster> getAll(){
    return (ArrayList<SKUMaster>) skuMasterRepo.findAll();
}
```

**SKUMasterRepo**

public interface SKUMasterRepo extends CrudRepository<SKUMaster, Integer>{

}

Comment: Can you show us the code from `SKUMasterService.getAll` and `SKUMasterController.getAll` ?

Comment: `Item implements ItemImpl` ?? skuMaster repo will fetch the SKUMaster entities, so something is missing here. I would guess that your mapping table is `UnitOfMeasure` , so there might be an issue there ? What do you mean by _If we make item property as an Arraylist of Items_ ? in which method ?